# HaxeNME with smartfox server integration

Tags: haxe, smartfoxserver

I'm working on a multiplayer game that required the use of Smartfox server, surely I want to start creating the client side in HaxeNME to enable exportation to iphone / android / web at the same time. From my awareness, smartfox only support Flash (and others but not Haxe) client library. So, anyone already working on this can point me to the correct library or direction ? I really don't want to rewrite the client library for Haxe as it's time consuming ?

Or should I use other technology to develop this game ? I tended to fall back to Unity if there are no other way to get haxeNME works with smartfox ... Any idea, everyone ?

thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

If your target is CPP/NME, I'm afraid your only option is to port the SmartFox AS3 client code to Haxe.

There are some tools that can be helpful for the task. Look for as3hx.

Comment: thanks man :( But as I said before, it's too time consuming to me, I might need to fall back to Unity3D then

Answer (score 2):

I've ported AS3 smartfox to haxe/cpp.
All works quite fine except the BlueBox module because of nme.net.URLRequest that doesn't support POST method yet :/
But in the futur I'll use the SWC on flash target, Java and objectiveC for android and iOS with nme.JNI and nmex support...

Comment: FYI -- The NME 3.2 beta that was released yesterday includes support for POST

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using SWC files from smartfox, haXe does not currently support SWC linking, however you can use them. You'll first have to unzip the SWC to extract the library.swf and add it with --swf-lib library.swf to your compiler parameters.

More information on http://haxe.org/manual/swc

Comment: thanks man, but that's not what i want as I'm not targeting Flash :(